# np.vectorize() changes input dtype np.float32 to float

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm having problems with `np.vectorize()` using following code:

```py
import bitstring as bs
import numpy as np

def get_bitstring(number, mode=None):
    """Get BitString based on internal representation of number."""
    if mode:
        return bs.pack(mode, number)
    double = (float, np.float64)
    single = (np.float32)
    if isinstance(number, double):
        mode = '>d'
    elif isinstance(number, single):
        mode = '>f'
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown type")
    return bs.pack(mode, number)

def vec_get_bitstring(arr):
    vec = np.vectorize(get_bitstring, otypes=[bs.BitStream])
    return vec(arr)

# Testarray
arr = np.array([np.float32(1),np.float32(2)], dtype=np.float32)
```

These are the results I'm getting:

```
[get_bitstring(x,) for x in arr]
# >> [BitStream('0x3f800000'), BitStream('0x40000000')]

vec_get_bitstring(are)
# >> array([BitStream('0x3ff0000000000000'),   BitStream('0x4000000000000000')], dtype=object)
```

np.vectorize() transforms the input `np.float32(x)` to `float(x)` before giving the data to `get_bitstring(x)`. Which of course sees a `float` and returns a 64-Bit number. Why is that? Why does `np.vectorize` change my input dtype from `np.float32(x)` to `float(x)`?

Answer (score 1):

`vectorize` is the wrong tool.

Plain list comprehension (or iteration) gives the desired element types:

```
In [66]: arr = np.array([1,2], dtype=np.float32)
In [67]: arr
Out[67]: array([ 1.,  2.], dtype=float32)
In [68]: [type(i) for i in arr]
Out[68]: [numpy.float32, numpy.float32]
In [70]: [type(i.item()) for i in arr]
Out[70]: [float, float]
```

`vectorize` is meant to make broadcasting arrays, to a function that only accepts scalar values, easy. It's most useful when your function takes several variables.   We'd have to dig into its code to see exactly where and how it is transforming the elements to scalars.  It's not trivial code; you loose a lot of control by using it.

Keep in mind that `vectorize` does not make any speed claims.

Maybe you need to explain why you are using `vectorize`.

---

If I define:

```
def foo(x):
    print(type(x))
    return x
vfoo = np.vectorize(foo)
```

It appears that the first call, the one used to determine the output type (if not defined), gets the `numpy` type.  But subsequent ones all get the underlying python type:

```
In [12]: vfoo(np.array([1,2,3.],np.int8))
<type 'numpy.int8'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
Out[12]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int8)

In [14]: vfoo(np.array(['string',2,3.],object))
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'float'>
Out[14]: 
array(['string', '2', '3.0'],  dtype='|S6')
```

There is a comment in the `vectorize` code about converting the args to object dtype arrays.  I didn't study the context, but we may be seeing this effect:

```
In [20]: type(np.array([1,2,3],np.float32)[0])
Out[20]: numpy.float32

In [21]: type(np.array([1,2,3],np.float32).astype(object)[0])
Out[21]: float
```

---

Here's a way of doing `dtype` object operations with a 2d array:

```
In [90]: x=np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)

In [91]: res=np.empty(x.shape,dtype=object)

In [92]: res.flat[:]=[type(i) for i in x.flat]

In [93]: res
Out[93]: 
array([[<type 'numpy.int32'>, <type 'numpy.int32'>],
       [<type 'numpy.int32'>, <type 'numpy.int32'>],
       [<type 'numpy.int32'>, <type 'numpy.int32'>]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Especially the last code bit I didn't know that. I'm using `np.vectorized` because real life input will be two n-dimensional numpy arrays which I have to transform into Bitstrings and do calculations on this level (e.g. XOR or Integer operations).

Comment: [Crossed the 5 min 'edit-comment'-threshold] I could write list comprehensions based on shape of the array but I would have to have a lot of sanity checks. And  `np.vectorize` looked really promising... :)

Comment: I added an example of creating an 2d object array from a 2d numeric one; using `flat` to iterate over the 1d equivalent.

Comment: Well. This might actually be a help. Right now I have a workaround using the `mode` argument in the function call, but I'll try this later...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the data type you want (float32) to types. it seems you have to specify exactly the output type you want.

Comment: The output is perfectly fine. The problem is that numpy is actually transforming the `np.float32` into `float` before calling the function `get_bitstring()` and this messes up the original intention of the function.